# How to get data from Play store API

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, google-play-console

I have a requirement to display following information from play store to admin panel.

- Users Comments/Reviews
- App installs/Uninstalls (weekly/monthly/quarterly)
- Android Vitals (Crashes, Anr, Performance)

In short I need to show most of the information in my `admin console` that we can see on play store console.

I looked into [Google Play Developer Api](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/) , but it looks like it does not provide much information out of `play store`.

The only useful things for me in this scenario are `Read Reviews`, `Reply to Reviews`, and `Edit Description`

I want to know, if there is any way out there to get above mentioned information from `play store console.`

Comment: That's all the GPD API can offer so don't think there's a way you can fetch comment/reviews as of now. 

For tracking Installs/Uninstalls and Android Vitals, there's a list from [8 Tools To Track Android And iOS App Uninstalls](https://appsamurai.com/8-tools-to-track-android-and-ios-app-uninstalls/) to see this:
Uninstall.io, Google Play Dev Console/applications, etc.

 Also, you can use [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/) for realtime crash reporting which helps you track, prioritize, and fix stability issues that erode your app quality.